# How to make auto break new line Text in FabricJS?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I want to make auto break new line Text when user typing a long text. Text's width is fixed ( behavior like attach video ). 
And user can drag middle left & middle right control point to change Text's width. 
How to make that Text in fabricJS ?

[image: video link] !

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand – but look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/illumine/Avvxn/) and [that](http://jsfiddle.net/willtonkin/24hs50vv/) example.

Comment: No Grabbing, Thank you for your suggestion. But today, I found out, class [fabric.TextBox](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Textbox.html) is enough for this requirement. _"Textbox class, based on IText, allows the user to resize the text rectangle and wraps lines automatically. Textboxes have their Y scaling locked, the user can only change width. Height is adjusted automatically based on the wrapping of lines."_